# How can I call Java functions from a C service in Android?

Tags: java, android, c, android-binder

I want to call the `maybeStartIpManager` function in [EthernetNetworkFactory](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/frameworks/opt/net/ethernet/java/com/android/server/ethernet/EthernetNetworkFactory.java) file in AOSP from a [C file](http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/external/wpa_supplicant_8/wpa_supplicant/wpas_glue.c) in the wpa_supplicant project. I found many examples of how Java services use binder to access code written in C. How can I use binder to achieve what I want? Is there an alternative other than using binder as a solution for my situation?

Comment: i see a problem in your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently I don't believe your question is specific enough to be answered. If you could edit it to include what you've tried and what isn't working that would help.

Comment: Hi @bbnumber2. I edited the question. Let me know if it is still not clear. Sorry for the inconvenience